# multiple divs show hide rows based on button click and value entered input

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

i have a table like div that iterates over 20 empty record sets the back end is not important here.  the image looks like attachment [20 record sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCsEL.jpg)

as you can see the repetitiveness is quite redundant here.  i need help with the following:

1-  user clicks button    Add more shipments

2-  if input with id="input-desc" has a value then javascript kicks and shows the next div record

only when these 2 conditions are met, can the next div class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc"
show.. so i want the list of divs class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc" to be hidden until user clicks Add Shipment then will the div show.. also i need at least one record set to show so the user can fill in the shipment details see pic below

[one shipment details should show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws9Uk.jpg)

```
 <div th:each="freight, itemStat : *{freightsDto}">
            <div class="row mtp">
                <div class="col-sm-8 w-50 desc">
                    <label class="row">Item description</label>
                    <input id="input-desc" class="row form-control" type="text"
                           th:field="*{freightsDto[__${itemStat.index}__].name}"
                           required="required">
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div id="toggleBtn" class="row mtp">
                <button  class="col-sm-12">
                    Add more shipments
                </button>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

Comment: where is `javascript` code ? Also , elaborate more on your problem.

Comment: i dont have the code if i did have the code i would have done it...

Comment: i updated the listing